# WordPress: Use different root url for wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Is this possible in wordpress?
I have a site https://mynormalsite.com with a WP-installation (in subdirectory).

Now I want to create a page "My Special Project", which url is not https://mynormalsite.com/myspecialproject but https://myspecialproject.com, which I own and is connect to the same web hotell. Is this possible to do without using iframe in the root of that page? I mean, so it can be managed within only WordPress (so client can do this easily in future without messing with ftp?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish it's called a "multisite". You can read more about it here: [WordPress Multisite vs. Multiple Sites](https://managewp.com/blog/wordpress-multisite-vs-multiple-sites) .

Comment: Thanks. Can I use a totally unique url:s or only subdomains (watching a tutorial now)?

Comment: You can use unique URLs for every WordPress multisite.